# Avoid android soft keyboard from resizing the layout. Or callback to hide views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I'm developing an app and I really need to avoid the keyboard from resizing the layout when the  keyboard is shown. I've already read TONS of posts in SO and also read about it in blogs but I can't find an answer that really works. My problem is that when the keyboards pops some views in the bottom of the screen are moved up so a lot of space is wasted with this views that are not necessary to be shown when the keyboard comes out.

So I have two possibilities or find a way that keyboard doesn't resize the layout or some kind of "keyboard is out" callback that let me hide the views that are useless when keyboard is shown. Any idea???

Help!!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in tha AndroidManifest when you declare your activity?
When you set this, than the activitiy won't be resized.